# Rules when calculating with limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits

My problem is inspired by [If $g$ is continuous and $f(a)=0$ then $f\cdot g$ is differentiable at $a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3878264/579544) .

Let's assume that $g:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n $ is continuous at $a$, $f:\mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable at $a$ and $f(a)=0$. Let be $A$ a $m\times n$ matrix with the property $\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)-A(x-a)}{\Vert x-a\Vert}=0$. Now consider the following limit:
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(a)-Ag(a)(x-a)}{\Vert x-a\Vert}=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)g(x)-Ag(a)(x-a)}{\Vert x-a\Vert}=\cdots
$$
I am not sure if I can proceed with following manipulations:
$$\cdots=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{\Vert x-a\Vert}g(\lim\limits_{x\to a}x)-\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{Ag(a)(x-a)}{\Vert x-a\Vert}=
\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{\Vert x-a\Vert}g(a)-\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{Ag(a)(x-a)}{\Vert x-a\Vert}=\\\left(\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{\Vert x-a\Vert}-\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{A(x-a)}{\Vert x-a\Vert}\right)g(a)=\lim\limits_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-A(x-a)}{\Vert x-a\Vert}g(a)=0.
$$

It feels wrong but I am not sure at which step I have violated any limit rule?

Comment: Why don't you write down exactly which limit rules you are using? That would help you see where the problem is.

Comment: @MatthewTowers , I think I got it, the main problem is that I did not check if the individual limits exist. The rules $\lim\limits_{x\to a} \left(F(x)-G(x)\right)=\lim\limits_{x\to a} F(x)-\lim\limits_{x\to a}G(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a} \left(F(x)\cdot G(x)\right)=\lim\limits_{x\to a} F(x)\cdot\lim\limits_{x\to a}G(x)$ only hold if $\lim\limits_{x\to a} F(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to a}G(x)$ both exist (what I don't know). Is this correct?

Comment: you're right, the individual limits must exist.

Comment: for example. $Ag(a)$ is constant and potentially invertible, so you could be asserting the existence of $\lim_{x \to a} (x-a)/||x-a||$.